# Empty (zero height) documents in Haskell prettyprinter

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

Is there a way to create a zero height empty document in [prettyprinter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter)? emptyDoc has a height of 1 which then results in empty lines. I would also like to avoid using Maybes to solve this.

Comment: Can you avoid needing it? (If you say a bit about why you think you need it, we may be able to help you avoid it.)

Comment: I'm composing a report / document out of several optional parts. It can be avoided using Maybes but that's just more code in comparison with what could be just empty documents.

Comment: A useful function could be `catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]` in Data.Maybe

Comment: You're not the only one to have a problem  with `prettyprinter`'s handling of empty documents: https://github.com/quchen/prettyprinter/issues/159 Feel free to chime in! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [there isn't](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/prettyprinter-1.2.1/docs/src/Data.Text.Prettyprint.Doc.Internal.html#Doc):

```
data Doc ann =
    Fail
    | Empty
    | Char !Char
    | Text !Int !Text
    | Line
    | FlatAlt (Doc ann) (Doc ann)
    | Cat (Doc ann) (Doc ann)
    | Nest !Int (Doc ann)
    | Union (Doc ann) (Doc ann)
    | Column (Int -> Doc ann)
    | WithPageWidth (PageWidth -> Doc ann)
    | Nesting (Int -> Doc ann)
    | Annotated ann (Doc ann)
```

None of these correspond to anything with a height under 1 -- the closest is `Empty`, but this is interpreted as a height-1 empty document (and your `emptyDoc` is `emptyDoc = Empty`).

It does seem a bit infelicitous. Perhaps a patch to the library to add a truly empty document would be considered; it would certainly be the cleanest approach.

Another possibility would be to use the annotation mechanism to make a "this chunk has height 0" annotation, and write your own renderer that handles this annotation.

But using `Maybe (Doc foo)` or `[Doc foo]` as appropriate in positions where you may need a 0-height document is likely to be the most straightforward way to make progress.